# Concatenar en un ciclo en C

Tags: c, algoritmos, loops

Tengo un problema, cuando quiero ir concatenando es la variable de tipo string temp cada vez que se repite el ciclo esta variable se reinicia. ¿Por qué pasa esto y qué puedo hacer para solventarlo?

```
void processData( int *digits, int digitLen ) {
  //char numLetter[];
  char temp[] = "";
  int i,c,j;

  if( digitLen >= 3 ) {
    int m = digitLen - 2;
    // restamos 2 porque solo nos interesan aquí los número
    // a partir de 3 dígitos, es decir, a partir de 100

    for( i = m, j = m - 1, c = 0; i >= 1; i--, j--, c++ ) {
      int g = digits[c]-1; // take the number to add the unit

      if( g == 0 )
        continue;

      strcat(temp,a[0][g]);
      strcat(temp," ");
      strcat(temp,a[3][j]); 
      strcat(temp," ");
    }
    strcat(temp,"and ");
  }
  printf("%s \n",temp);
}
```

Estoy haciendo un programa que devuelva un número en letra, para eso quiero ir agregando concatenando a la variable temp. Así:suponemos el número es 1350. Primero temp = "", se recorre el primer número 
1 entonces agrego a temp= "One thousand", luego un espacio y concateno: 3-> three hundred y temp sería temp = "One thousand three hundred " y así pero cuando se repite el ciclo se borra lo que estaba antes en la variable temp.

Comment: puedes declarar la variable `temp` de mas elementos? como `char temp[1000] = "";`

Answer (score 1):

La verdad, no entiendo muy bien tu código:

```
void processDataint( int *digits, int digitLen ) {
```

¿ Pasas un puntero a entero ? ¿ Eso es porque en otra parte has descompuesto el número a procesar en sus distintos dígitos ?

Y supongo que `a[]` es del tipo `char *a[]`, un arreglo de punteros a cadenas, en el que guardas los textos a añadir. Sin embargo, luego haces cosas como `a[0][g]`, con lo que sería `char **a[]`, pero no se me ocurre porqué.

Bueno, al tema. `strcat( dest, other )` **no gestiona la memória**; se supone que, al llamarla, `dest` **tiene espacio** para añadir la otra cadena.

Sin embargo, no veo que añadas ese espacio. No hay llamadas a `realloc( )`, ni a `malloc( )`, ni a `calloc( )`.

Al hacerlo así, estás **sobreescribiendo** la pila; el efecto de esto es *indefinido*; puedes recibir un fallo del sistema operativo (tipo error de protección general), sobreescribir las variables internas de la función, o cualquier otro efecto *curioso*.

Suponiendo que escojamos llamar a `realloc( )`, `tmp` **no puede estar en la pila**; solo sirve para punteros a memoria dinámica, con lo que es necesario un cambio en la declaración de `temp`:

```
char *temp = malloc( 1 );
*temp = 0;
```

El uso correcto de la función `strcat( )`, en tu caso, sería algo parecido a:

```
....
  if( g == 0 )
    continue;

  lengthToAdd = strlen( a[0][g] ) + strlen( a[3][j] + 7;
  // " " + " " + "and " + '\0' = 7;

  tmp2 = realloc( temp, sizeof( temp ) + lengthToAdd );

  if( !tmp2 ) {
    // ERROR. NO HAY MEMORIA.
  } else {
    temp = tmp2;
  }

  strcat( temp, a[0][g] );
  strcat( temp, " " );
  strcat( temp, a[3][j] ); 
  strcat( temp, " " );
}
strcat( temp,"and " );
```

}

Tendriamos que declarar las variables implicadas:

```
char *tmp2;
size_t lengthToAdd;
```

Con eso, tus cadenas se añadiran correctamente.

Comment: Gracias, excelente tu explicación. Perdón si no fue muy específico. SI el arreglo a es donde se encuentran las cadenas de los números y la variable digits contiene el arreglo de los digitos. Por ejm = num = 1555. EL arreglo sería [1,5,5,5] . Me cuestan un poco las cadenas en C . Gracias otra vez.  Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías usar sprintf, inicias la cadena con un caracter nulo para que no te tire errores, eso hice en Latino para hacer el formato de la fecha, quedando algo así:

```
sis.fecha("el año de hoy es %a y el mes es %mm")
```

url: https://github.com/primitivorm/latino/blob/master/src/libsys.c#L82-L189

Este es un ejemplo de como podrías seguir copiando en un ciclo más caracteres con sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    char *cadena = malloc(20); // indico el tamaño de la memoria que voy a usar
    sprintf(cadena, "%c", 0); // puedes ingresar un valor nulo para no tener errores en caso de iniciarla de 0
    char *cad1 = "123456"; // esta es una cadena donde ingreso los númericos que meteré en 'cadena'
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(cad1); i++) {
        sprintf(cadena, "%s%c", cadena, cad1[i]); // hago una copia de caracter por carater de 'cad1' a 'cadena', hago que retome lo que ya tiene cadena y siga copiando.
    }
    printf("%s\n", cadena); // imprimo el resultado
    free(cadena); // libero la memoria
}
```